# LINQ / EF - Using GroupBy to return values to a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

In my MVC 3 application I'm using the following query:

```
var items = context.QuoteLines.Include("DaybookVehicles").Where(x => x.EnquiryID == id).GroupBy(x=>x.VehicleID).ToList();
return View(items);
```

Then in my view I have this at the top:

```
@model IEnumerable<myApp.Areas.DayBook.Models.DayBookQuoteLines>
```

But this throws an error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,myApp.Areas.DayBook
.Models.DayBookQuoteLines]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[myapp.Areas.DayBook.Models.DayBookQuoteLines]'.
```

How do I use a group by in this case? As I'd like to group each of my `QuoteLines` to their matching `VehicleID`

## Edit

QuoteLines Model:

```
public class DayBookQuoteLines
{
    [Key]
    public int QuoteLineID { get; set; }

    public int EnquiryID { get; set; }

    public virtual int VehicleID { get; set; }

    public virtual DaybookVehicles Vehicle { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Item Number:")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ItemNumber { get; set; }

    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Vehicles Model:

```
public class DaybookVehicles
{
    [Key]
    public int VehicleID { get; set; }

    public int EnquiryID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DayBookQuoteLines> QuoteLines { get; set; }

    public string vrm { get; set; }

    public string make { get; set; }

    public string model { get; set; }

    public string engine_size { get; set; }

    public string fuel { get; set; }
}
```

I think I have this setup correctly, but each Vehicle can have a collection of QuoteLines attached to it!

Comment: You use it by first reading the documentation, then reading the error code and then explaining what do you want, because the query and @model say something complelty different.

Comment: We need your model(s) to help you !

Comment: The query returns (many) *groups*, each of which has one `VehicleID` and many `QuoteLines`. Your view is trying to display simply `QuoteLines`. These are different types of data. Decide whether you want your view to display *groups* or *lines*, and amend your query appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The model type is different from the type returned by the function .I think that the appropriate model for this view is

```
@model IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, DayBookQuoteLines>>
```

and there is no need for the ToList at the query

Comment: Just a question regarding this, why is the first value an int? Is that due to VehicleID being an int value?

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff Yes , which is the grouping key