# How to display group data in html table asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

Hi i have this table where i want to show group data from controller, it returns objects grouped by meeting id

`var res = db.MinuteofMeet.GroupBy(x => x.MeetID).ToList();`

view

```
                    {
                        int i = 1;
                        foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            DatContext dbs = new DatContext();
                    <tr>
                        <td hidden>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MeetID)
                        </td>
                         <td>
                            @Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", item.CDate))
                        </td>
                        <td>
                      
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubjectDetail)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", item.Meetdate))
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReviewedBy)*@
                            Demo

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.responsible)
                        </td>
                        <td hidden>  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.action_type)</td>

                        <td>
                            <img data-id="@item.Comment" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#commentsmodal" class="datimage" src="~/MatAssets/images/plus.png">
                        </td>
```

but when I run the application its throwing an error saying

`` The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,SmartBookingPro.Models.MinuteOfMeeting]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SmartBookingPro.Models.MinuteOfMeeting]'. ``

and this is my modal

```
{
    [Table("tbl_minofmeet")]
    public class MinuteOfMeeting
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int MeetID { get; set; }
        public string RoomName { get; set; }
        //public string Client { get; set; }
        //public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Minutes { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
                   
        public string ReviewedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CDate { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string Minstatus { get; set; }
        public string Task_status { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Meetdate { get; set; }
       
       

        public string responsible { get; set; }
        public string action_type { get; set; }
      
        public string SubjectDetail { get; set; }
```

I have no prior experience with SQL groupdata and I tried looking for solutions online but nothing is working so far, how can I fix this? thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ / EF - Using GroupBy to return values to a View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497347/linq-ef-using-groupby-to-return-values-to-a-view)

Answer (score 0):

Your model should be @model IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, MinuteOfMeeting>>

- var res = db.MinuteofMeet.GroupBy(x => x.MeetID) instead of ToList()

Comment: Hi Thanks for your replay, after doing the following changes im unable to populate the table because the modal doesn't show any table coulm names anymore, what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

For your var res:
If you remove the part of .GroupBy(x => x.MeetID)
It will be a List of MinutesOfMeeting

Now your var res is most likely a List<IGrouping<int, MinutesOfMeeting>>

After a GroupBy, you could / should do a Select like:
.Select(mom => new MintuesOfMeetingModel { MeetId = mom.FirstOrDefault() }).ToList()

You might need to make a new model to implement this

Comment: so i have to chnage to model in view to view modal and the rest works just like what I have already done?

Comment: Yes, in your view you will be using the new viewModel. You will instantiate the viewmodel with the Select() example. I think you will be there then (if not, almost)